# Handle a Button Event: index.js does not appear

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am currently going through the beginner tutorial, I have gotten to the "Handle a button event" section where it asks to open the index.js file. Where was this file supposed to be located, as well as when was it added in during the tutorial? This file does not appear when I search it.

Comment: If you have installed the latest [Tools for Apache Cordova update 10](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release-update-10/). `index.js` is under "project folder->www->scripts->index.js".

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the Typescript version of the blank Cordova template to create your project?  If so that is why you would not see any index.js.  Start over using the Javascript version instead of Typescript. Just create a new project as usual and find Cordova under Javascript. This happened to me.